# Can I use Glide to get refined/desired bitmap to draw on canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-glide

How do I use Glide Library to get the bitmap because I want to draw that bitmap image on canvas.
Glide only allows me to add image to ImageView.

Is there any way where I can get the refined bitmap by Glide so that I can draw that to canvas.

Currently I am using

```
Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), wallpaper_image_id);
```

and I get this error

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 43776012 byte allocation with 16767008 free bytes and 40MB until OOM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a target is what you need. Take a look [Here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Custom-targets).

```
Glide.with(yourApplicationContext))
    .load(youUrl)
    .asBitmap()
    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(myWidth, myHeight) {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation anim) {
            // Do something with bitmap here.
        }
    };
```

Inside the `onResourceReady`you've got the bitmap ready to be loaded where you want.

**EDIT**

Your app crashes because you need to run code in the ui thread. Try this:

```
// Get a handler that can be used to post to the main thread
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());

Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {....} // Your code goes inside the run method
};
mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
```

Comment: Thanks @Samuele but now Gives FATALException as. `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must call this method on the main thread`

Comment: Well, clearly now you are calling this method in the wrong thread! ahahah
Where are you calling the code? You should call it from the UI thread basically.

Comment: From here...   `public class SnowThread extends Thread { }` which I have created to snow constantly on my wallpaper. And I am calling it from its `run()` method. It needs to be there.

Comment: it doenst let me put bitmap as parameter for simpletarget it must extend drawable